# Issue with Design Patterns recognition

Tags: java, design-patterns

I need help with Design Patterns recognition. Here is my Java code

```
public class A extend B {
  public A (String arg1){
    super(arg1);
  }

  public C newInstance(String arg2){
    return new C(arg1, arg2);
  }
}
```

Any ideas which Pattern is it?

UPD

```
public abstract class B {
    protected final String arg;

    public B(String arg) {
        this.arg = arg;
    }

    public String getArg() {
        return arg;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a [creational pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern).

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Which one? Is it a Prototype?

Comment: It has elements of prototype, but is most definitely not prototype.

Comment: So it's mostly a factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely factory pattern because `newInstance()` creates instance of other class. There is also a tip of abstract factory. Probably you posted only a fragment of your question. Probably they mean that `B` is a base factory class, `A` is one of the factory implementations, so its `newInstance()` method creates instances of concrete class `C`.

EDIT

Yes, sure I agree with @Sotirios Delimanolis: factory belongs to group of creational patterns.

Comment: I think B is not a factory or abstract factory class.

Comment: @barbara, you are welcome to think what you want, however this is the classic example of factory. Concerning abstract factory, I cannot be sure since I do not have code of `B`, however I can suppose that if factory class extends other class it *probably* an example of abstract factory.